# Maven Git commit with white space is failing

Tags: git, maven, directory, whitespace, osb

I am trying to mvn release:prepare to Git. But it is throwing the following error :

> Error inside systemOut parser: Illegal character in path at index 0:
>   "DevelopmentCode/MavenDeploymentVersion/MvnDeplVer/.data/maven/configjar/configfwk/osbinstance1552976461660/OSB11gConfig/core/System/JNDI%20Providers/_folderdata"

I manually removed the whitespace in the folder name as JNDIProviders. Now I am able to successfully run mvn release:prepare to Git. Is there any other way than manually changing folder name? Is it a bug? I am using maven release plugin version 2.5.1 .

Thanks in advance for your response.